# Django merging 2 model instances issue with m2m fields which specifies an intermediary model

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I'm using a script to automate merging 2 Django model instances (so it can be used for any kind of model in my system). But there is a problem when it comes to the part that handle m2m fields which specifies an intermediary model (using `through` parameter when this field defined), I get the error: `AttributeError: Cannot use remove() on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model. Use <MyModel>'s Manager instead`

```
# Migrate all many to many references from alias object to primary object.
for related_many_object in get_all_related_many_to_many_objects(alias_object):
    alias_varname = related_many_object.get_accessor_name()
    obj_varname = related_many_object.field.name

    if alias_varname is not None:
        # standard case
        related_many_objects = getattr(alias_object, alias_varname).all()
    else:
        # special case, symmetrical relation, no reverse accessor
        related_many_objects = getattr(alias_object, obj_varname).all()
    for obj in related_many_objects.all():
        getattr(obj, obj_varname).add(primary_object) #This line raises the AttributeError
        getattr(obj, obj_varname).remove(alias_object)
```

Here is the function that return all m2m field of the object which need to be merged:

```
def get_all_related_many_to_many_objects(obj):
    return [
        f for f in obj._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True)
        if f.many_to_many and f.auto_created
    ]
```

I have 2 question about this case:

1. Is there any built-in functions that allows me to distinguish m2m fields which specifies intermediary model from m2m fields which doesn't? (Because with the normal m2m fields this add() function seemingly works well).
2. With m2m fields which specifies, how can I gracefully remove/add a model instance to that relationship?

Thank for your time!